# Deleting the maximum element in BST

Tags: binary-search-tree

Some of the code below seems too obvious, traversing the tree using its right most branch since that is where all the max values are.However, I don't understand a few things about this code I saw in Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms book.

```
     public void deleteMax() {
     if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("");
     root = deleteMax(root);
     assert check();
     }

    private Node deleteMax(Node x) {
    if (x.right == null) return x.left;
    x.right = deleteMax(x.right);
    x.size = size(x.left) + size(x.right) + 1;
    return x;
    }
```

In the private method why do we return the left element if the right child of x is null ?From my understanding x would be the maximum if x has no right children and is the right most node we could go to.Also I don't understand when do we return x in the last line of the 2nd method.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` doesn't have a right child then `x` is the maximum node. We "delete" it by returning `x.left` (the new max node). We return `x` after we've modified its right subtree.